# gulp watch not updating JSON file

Tags: json, gulp, handlebars.js, watch

Im using gulp to watch a json file, when it's edited I need to see the changes reflected in the browser, but it only works if I stop the watch and run gulp again:

I'm watching for changes in the json file here:

```
gulp.task('watch', function() {
     gulp.watch('./src/layout.json', ['compileHandlebars']);
});
```

in the task:

```
gulp.task('compileHandlebars', function () {
    var buildSettings = require('./src/layout.json');
    var templateData = buildSettings,
    options = {
        batch : ['./src/assets/templates/'],
    }
    gulp.src('./src/index.handlebars')
        .pipe(handlebars(templateData, options))
        .pipe(rename('index.html'))
        //.pipe(gulp.dest('./src/compiled'));
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Figured this out. I needed to add the following to the top of my task in order to clear the json file from cache:

```
delete require.cache[require.resolve('./src/layout.json')]
```

The whole task:

```
gulp.task('compileHandlebars', function () {
        delete require.cache[require.resolve('./src/layout.json')]
        var buildSettings = require('./src/layout.json');
        var templateData = buildSettings,
        options = {
            batch : ['./src/assets/templates/'],
        }

        gulp.src('./src/index.handlebars')
            .pipe(handlebars(templateData, options))
            .pipe(rename('index.html'))
            .pipe(htmlmin({collapseWhitespace: true}))
            .pipe(htmlmin({removeComments: true}))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
    });
```